# n thread consensus queues

Tags: concurrency, consensus, queues

Its generally agreed that wait free queues have a consensus number of 2.
But what about this following code for a consensus protocol for a queue.
How is it that this does not go against the idea above?

(Im going to have a wild guess and say this code is not wait free?)

lets say we have a queue with 3 elements, and there are 3 threads. The top element about to be popped from the queue is 1, the rest of the values in the queue is -1

```
class ConsensusQueue()
   queue = new Queue()
   queue.enqueue(-1)
   queue.enqueue(1)
   queue.enqueue(1)
   atomic_reg = new AtomicRegister()

def decide(value):
    d = queue.dequeue()
    if d == -1:
       atomic_reg.set(value)
    return atomic_reg
```